# Determine end of stream in MultiPartReaderStream in ASP.NET Core 5 WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to create a REST API that takes a large file and uploads it to SharePoint.  I am using the Microsoft recommended approach to upload large files via Web API as shown below.  Once uploaded I am putting them in a SharePoint document library.  Since these are large files the upload to SharePoint must be chunked.  In order to accomplish this I need to know when the stream is completed (no more bytes coming in) or the stream length ahead of time.  I cannot seem to find either.  At them moment I am streaming the file to disk then uploading it to SharePoint.  This is obviously not the most efficient process.  Instead I would like stream the file directly to  SharePoint.  In order to do so I need to know when to stop reading the stream.  Thus either need to know the stream length ahead of time or need some attribute on the stream that indicates the stream has completed reading.

The input stream from the multpart reader is a  MultiPartReaderStream.   This stream does not have the length set.  It does have a property called FinalBoundaryFound, which I think I could use, however this class is an internal class so I cannot access this propery.  Only the base stream propertys are available.  The MultiPartSection and MultiPartReader do not seem to have an indicator.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can either get the stream length or determine when the stream has reached its end?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route(nameof(UploadLargeFile))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadLargeFile()
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Request;

        // validation of Content-Type
        // 1. first, it must be a form-data request
        // 2. a boundary should be found in the Content-Type
        if (!request.HasFormContentType ||
            !MediaTypeHeaderValue.TryParse(request.ContentType, out var mediaTypeHeader) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaTypeHeader.Boundary.Value))
        {
            return new UnsupportedMediaTypeResult();
        }

        var reader = new MultipartReader(mediaTypeHeader.Boundary.Value, request.Body);
        var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();

        // This sample try to get the first file from request and save it
        // Make changes according to your needs in actual use
        while (section != null)
        {
            var hasContentDispositionHeader = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(section.ContentDisposition,
                out var contentDisposition);

            if (hasContentDispositionHeader && contentDisposition.DispositionType.Equals("form-data") &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileName.Value))
            {
                // Don't trust any file name, file extension, and file data from the request unless you trust them completely
                // Otherwise, it is very likely to cause problems such as virus uploading, disk filling, etc
                // In short, it is necessary to restrict and verify the upload
                // Here, we just use the temporary folder and a random file name


                I would like to implement a while loop here that reads bytes off the stream and sends them to sharepont but
                cannot determine when to stop reading.

                return Ok();
            }

            section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
        }

        // If the code runs to this location, it means that no files have been saved
        return BadRequest("No files data in the request.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can block large files in Javascript and upload them to SharePoint using restapi.

Offical doc: [Upload a file by using the REST API and jQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery)

#### Block large file

[The example code](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/276717/how-to-upload-large-files-onto-sharepoint-using-rest-api-and-jquery/276773#276773) for your reference.

Comment: I have no problem iplementing c# code that does exactly what the java scrirpt does.  In fact that is what I am doing now.  This is possible because you know the length of a file stream.  So you know how many bytes to send.  The MultiPartReader stream does not support file length.  This is my problem.